# Is Royal Canin Feline Urinary SO 33 the same as Urinary SO?

Tags: cats, diet

Is Royal Canin cat food "Urinary SO 33" the same as "Urinary SO"?  I can't find any solid information on what the difference between them might be, or if it's just a re-branding.  Urinary SO 33 is [still for sale](https://www.petflow.com/product/royal-canin-veterinary-diet/royal-canin-veterinary-diet-feline-urinary-so-dry-cat-food) in some places (note name on the package in the picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to [Royal Canin on Twitter](https://twitter.com/RoyalCanin/status/616241158033833984). While this isn't a verified account, it is the account that Royal Canin lists on their webpage, so it should be trustworthy and written by someone from the company.

The representative said

> This is simply just a package change. You will only see it labeled as Urinary SO now.